# How to convert four and 2 space indented text to json format

Tags: python, json

I have been spending hours to convert the space indented text to JSON. In my raw text data, nested values are indented by 4 spaces and key:value are indented by 2 spaces. I am trying to make a JSON out of them.

## My attempt

```py
import json
from pprint import pprint

lines = raw_text.strip().split('\n')
result = {}
stack = [(0, result)]

for line in lines:
    indent, content = line.split(':', 1)
    indent_level = len(indent) - len(indent.lstrip())
    key = content.strip()
    value = None if key == "null" else {}

    print(indent_level, stack[-1][0])

    while indent_level <= stack[-1][0]:
        stack.pop()

    parent = stack[-1][1] # i am getting index error
    parent[key] = value
    stack.append((indent_level, value))

j = json.dumps(result, indent=4)
```

## Raw data

```py
text = r"""
h0: 
    h1: de8
    h1b: null
    h1c: 
        h2: 
          h3: A
          h3a: S
          h3b: 
              h4: 
                h5: 81
    h1b:
      h1bi: null
      h1bii: null
"""
```

## Required

```
j = {
    "h0": {
        "h1a": "de8",
        "h1b": "null",
        "h1c": {
            "h2a": {
                "h3a": "A",
                "h3b": "S",
                "h3c": {
                    "h4a": {
                        "h5a": "81"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "h1d": {
            "h1di": "null",
            "h1dii": {
                "h2di": "hello",
                "h2dii": "hi"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `yaml` package? if not, try `yaml.safe_load(text)` and it should work fine. https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/

Comment: Great! I'm gonna add an answer as well, please accept that as the answer if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `yaml` package: https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/

The code will look like something like this:

```
import yaml

text = "<the_text_you_want_to_convert_to_json>"
json = yaml.safe_load(text)
print(json)
```

and the output is:

```
{'h0': {'h1': 'de8', 'h1b': {'h1bi': None, 'h1bii': None}, 'h1c': {'h2': {'h3': 'A', 'h3a': 'S', 'h3b': {'h4': {'h5': 81}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go (`without external lib`)

```
import pprint

text = r"""
h0: 
    h1: de8
    h1b: null
    h1c: 
        h2: 
          h3: A
          h3a: S
          h3b: 
              h4: 
                h5: 81
    h1b:
      h1bi: null
      h1bii: null
"""


def add_inner_dict(the_dict, keys):
    for k in keys[:-1]:
        the_dict = the_dict[k]
    d = {}
    the_dict[keys[-1]] = d
    return d


data = {}
current_dict = None
lines = text.split('\n')
key = None
path = []
for line in lines:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    entries = stripped_line.split(':')
    if len(entries) == 2 and entries[1]:
        current_dict[entries[0]] = entries[1].strip()
    else:
        if entries[0].strip():
            key = entries[0]
            path.append(key)
            current_dict = add_inner_dict(data, path)

pprint.pprint(data)
```

output

```
{'h0': {'h1': 'de8',
        'h1b': 'null',
        'h1c': {'h2': {'h3': 'A',
                       'h3a': 'S',
                       'h3b': {'h4': {'h1b': {'h1bi': 'null', 'h1bii': 'null'},
                                      'h5': '81'}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion of @DasaniT, this worked for me

```py
text = r"""
h0: 
    h1a: de8
    h1b: null
    h1c: 
        h2a: 
          h3a: A
          h3b: S
          h3c: 
              h4a: 
                h5a: 81
    h1d:
      h1di: null
      h1dii:
        h2di: hello
        h2dii: hi
"""

import yaml

j = yaml.safe_load(text)

print(j)
```